# Comparing innerHTML with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this setup:

```
var htmlOne = "$('.class1').children('.username').html()";
var htmlTwo = "$('.class2').html()";
if(htmlTwo *= htmlOne)
{stuff};
```

It is supposed to see if the inner html of htmlTwo matches the inner html of htmlOne in some way. Is this set up right?

Comment: Just so it's said, comparing two HTML substrings for equality is a very rickety way of comparing elements.  Consider something like `isEqualNode`.

Comment: I haven't used that before. How would it be used in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be assigned without double quotes

```
var htmlOne = $('.class1').children('.username').html();
var htmlTwo = $('.class2').html();

if(htmlTwo == htmlOne) {
   //stuff
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
var htmlOne = new String(htmlOne);
var htmlTwo = new String(htmlTwo);

if(htmlOne==htmlTwo){


}
```

Comment: The function within the if statement didn't do anything so I'm assuming that that doesn't work. I tried the function on its own and it does work.